# Nagios alert "ESX3 Critical - Error: Cannot complete login due to an incorrect user name or password" after changing root password via vSphere

Tags: vmware-esxi, nagios

I currently just inherited Nagios administration after an employee was let go a couple of days ago. As part of our procedures for exiting employees, we changed passwords for all accounts the employee had access to. I proceeded to change the root password for our ESXi servers via the vSphere Client. After doing so, Nagios started displaying alerts in regards to services not being able to be checked due to an incorrect user name or password.  After hours of research, I have been left to ask for help on here.

Currently, I have no idea as to where the problem resides.  I have checked the configuration for all the services on Nagios related to those ESXi hosts and there's no indicator of where I'd be able to update those services checks using the updated credentials.  The same goes for the ESXi hosts.  I've only looked through the vSphere Client settings, Nagios Web Interface, and the Nagios VM we are using.  Can anyone please guide me as to where I could go to remediate this dilemma of mine?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: What distro? How was Nagios installed (package/compiled)? What plugin are you using? Without this information, the only useful advice is "try grep -R"

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which linux distro you're running Nagios under, but if you're using [this plugin](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/*-Virtual-Environments/VMWare/Check-hardware-running-VMware-ESXi/details) to check ESXi, this information would be in one of the definition files that's probably in /etc/nagios or /etc/nagios3, or a subdirectory.  (Is it in commands.cfg?)  Look for an entry like

```
./check_esx_wbem.py https://myesxi:5989 root password
```

(If you're not using that particular plugin, well, it's probably in either one of those directories or in whatever your server's equivalent of /usr/lib/nagios/plugins is.

(P.S.  There are more VMware plugins [here](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/*-Virtual-Environments/VMWare).  If the above one isn't what you're using, maybe one of those is.)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and could not figure out how to change the password for monitoring through the web-interface.  However, I tracked down the user/password file on the nagiosxi server and changed it there and all is good.

To find where the password file is located to change, go to one of the Service reporting the error, go to the configuration tab and select "Re-configure this service".  The first tab is Monitoring.  You will there under "Monitor the service with this command".

Mine said "check_esx3_host!/usr/local/nagiosxi/etc/components/vmware/001_srv_vm1_auth.txt!CPU!"

The only thing I cared about was the path /usr/local/nagiosxi/etc/components/vmware/001_srv_vm1_auth.txt.

I ssh'ed into the server and using vim I updated the file with the new user/pass combo.  Then on nagiosxi web I forced an immediate check and service back in green!

Hope this helps.

Ramsey